# Native query doen't work from crudRepository- spring?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, hibernate-envers

There is application on spring, jpa, hibernate-envers(history)

I have two table `UserRecord` and `UserRecord_AUD`(create by hibernate-enver)
In Jpa I have crudRepository to read data from database.

My crudRepository created only for `UserRecord` table.

How to get all records using userRecordRepository from `UserRecord_AUD` table?

so, my repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRecord, String> {}
```

I tried to create custom native method

```
@Query(value = "select h.PR_KEY, h.name, h.surname, h.age, h.REV as VERSION, h.META from USRERECORD_AUD h where h.PR_KEY in (?1)", nativeQuery = true)
List<USerRecord> findHistoryByIds(List<String> ids);
```

but, if I wrote same user 3 time(1 write and 2 update), I expected, that in 
`UserRecord` table there is only 1 record(fresh) and in history other 2

my expected result is get all records from `UserRecord_AUD`

```
____________________________
11-22 Tanya Ivanova 22 1 ...
11-22 Tanya Ivanova 4  2 ...
11-22 Tanya Ivanova 23 3 ...
____________________________
```

my actual result is returned 3 same records from UserRecord table.

```
____________________________
11-22 Tanya Ivanova 23 3 ...
11-22 Tanya Ivanova 23 3 ...
11-22 Tanya Ivanova 23 3 ...
____________________________
```

Comment: You are returning entities and you cannot do that from a SQL without a sql result mapping. Hence you get the actual entities. Return a `List<Object[]>` to get a tuple of the result and manually map that.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you! Is there more buaty way to make this operation?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have field in that I have serialized byte array, but query returns Proxy in this object.

Comment: You should be using `AuditReader` to read from the Envers audit schema.  There are a number of nuances depending on the table mappings your entity has that its critical to let Envers build and execute the historical queries rather than writing them yourself.